# OctoberCMS plugin authoring: Problems with has-many relationships - class not found

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I'm really struggling to get OctoberCMS relationships to work in a plugin that I'm writing.  I have two tables: products and product_images.  There is a one-to-many relationship between products and product_images.

In my products model, I have:

```
public $hasMany = [
    'product_images' => ['Bt/Shop/Models/ProductImages']
];
```

I have a model called ProductImages located in plugins/bt/shop/models/ProductImages.php.  The model is defined as:

```
<?php namespace Bt\Shop\Models;

use Model;

class ProductImages extends Model
{
    public $table = 'bt_shop_product_images';

    protected $dates = ['published_at'];

    public static $allowedSortingOptions = array(
        'name asc' => 'Name (ascending)',
        'name desc' => 'Name (descending)',
        'updated_at asc' => 'Updated (ascending)',
        'updated_at desc' => 'Updated (descending)',
        'published_at asc' => 'Published (ascending)',
        'published_at desc' => 'Published (descending)',
    );

    public $preview = null;

    public $belongsTo = [
        'products' => ['Bt/Shop/Models/Products']
    ];

    ...
```

And the definition of my Products model looks like this:

```
<?php namespace Bt\Shop\Models;

use Model;

class Products extends Model
{

    public $table = 'bt_shop_products';

    protected $dates = ['published_at'];

    public static $allowedSortingOptions = array(
        'name asc' => 'Name (ascending)',
        'name desc' => 'Name (descending)',
        'updated_at asc' => 'Updated (ascending)',
        'updated_at desc' => 'Updated (descending)',
        'published_at asc' => 'Published (ascending)',
        'published_at desc' => 'Published (descending)',
    );

    public $preview = null;

    public $hasMany = [
        'product_images' => ['Bt/Shop/Models/ProductImages']
    ];
```

The error that I'm getting is:

> Class 'ProductImages' not found
>
> /var/www/mysite/public/vendor/october/rain/src/Database/Model.php line
>   772

I believe that when the Product hasMany relationship is being defined, somehow the code does not know about the ProductImages class.  The code in Model.php, line 772 is:

```
public function hasMany($related, $primaryKey = null, $localKey = null, $relationName = null)
{
    if (is_null($relationName))
        $relationName = $this->getRelationCaller();

    $primaryKey = $primaryKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();
    $localKey = $localKey ?: $this->getKeyName();
    $instance = new $related;

    return new HasMany($instance->newQuery(), $this, $instance->getTable().'.'.$primaryKey, $localKey, $relationName);
}
```

In my case, the variable named $related is equal to Bt/Shop/Models/ProductImages.  I printed it out to be sure.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Ben.  The Model.php that I quoted comes with the OctoberCMS.  I didn't write that Model.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.  I was using forward slashes instead of back slashes in my belongsTo and hasMany definitions:

Old (broken):

```
public $belongsTo = [
    'products' => ['Bt/Shop/Models/Products']
];
```

New (working):

```
public $belongsTo = [
    'products' => ['Bt\Shop\Models\Products']
];
```

Cheers,
Bret